# example for getting remote data into listbox using webservices

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I want to display list of items coming from  remote database into list box using web services
After adding the service reference what can i do for displaying the data on list box
give me any example or procedure for this task.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

Your service reference created some classes. One of them is a proxy class. Create an instance of this class, register for its events (if calls are asynchronous) and call the appropriate WS methods on the proxy object. Save the result in a variable and bind your listbox' items to the variable.

More exact explanations are not possible, because they depend on your service and other circumstances. However, you should be able to find the answer to your question by sarching the internet for some minutes.